# How do I DISTINCT a query when using a DATE() query on datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, combobox, distinct

I have the code below and works fine BUT I get multiple duplicate dates, obviously this is because they have many time stamps through the day but I'm only interested in the date, is there a way to DISTINCT the combo box after I have run the query?

```
 <select name="closeddate" class="box" value="No filter applied" id="closeddate">
<option>No filter applied</option><?php
$sql1= "SELECT * FROM tbl_jobs where STATUS = 'closed'";
$result = mysql_query($sql1);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$datedata = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data['close_date']));
echo "<option>$datedata</option>";
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQLNM.png)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(close_date,"%Y-%m-%d") close_date FROM tbl_jobs where STATUS = 'closed'`

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: If you are a beginner how are you using code that is 20 years old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use as the SQL:

```sql
select distinct date(close_date) as close_date
from tbl_jobs
where STATUS = 'closed'
```

And so (updated to use mysqli):

```php
<select name="closeddate" class="box" value="No filter applied" id="closeddate">
<option>No filter applied</option>
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT distinct date(close_date) as close_date FROM tbl_jobs where STATUS = 'closed'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql1);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //$datedata = date('d-m-Y, strtotime($data['close_date']));
    $date = new DateTime($data['close_date']);
    $datedata = $date->format('d-m-Y')
    echo "<option>$datedata</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

If you want MySQL to do the date formatting, then:

```php
<select name="closeddate" class="box" value="No filter applied" id="closeddate">
<option>No filter applied</option>
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT distinct date_format(close_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as close_date FROM tbl_jobs where STATUS = 'closed'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql1);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $datedata = $data['close_date'];
    echo "<option>$datedata</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```